# Show that the function is equal to its Taylor polynomial for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ when $n \geq k$.

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, solution-verification

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $T_n(x)$ be a Taylor polynomial for $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_{k-1}x^{k-1} + a_kx^k$ of order n about $x_0$. Then I have to argue that
$$
T_n(x) = p(x) \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R} \ \text{whenever} \ n \geq k
$$
I have tried to solve this several times but my TA has told me that I was not right in my argumentation and has asked me to use a sentence in the my Analysis book.

From the definition, in my book, I know that the remainder is defined as

$$
R_nf(x) = \frac{1}{n!} \int_{x_0}^x f^{(n+1)}(t)(x-t)^n dt
$$
but to use this formula I need to ensure that $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an open interval, that $x_0 \in I$ and lastly that $f \in C^\infty(I)$. Is it correct that every polynomial f satisfies $f \in C^\infty(I)$? I think it is but I am not sure. Can you verify? And if so to argue for that $T_n(x) = p(x)$ which must mean that $R_nf(x) = 0$ is the following calculation correct?
$$
R_nf(x) = \frac{1}{n!} \int_{x_0}^x f^{(n+1)}(t)(x-t)^n dt = \frac{1}{n!} \int_{x_0}^x 0(x-t)^ndt = 0
$$
As I have calculated that $f^{(n)} = n!a_k$ which must mean that $f^{(n+1)} = 0$ and thus the above integral must equal to zero. Is this approach alright?

Note: I got this answer last time I asked [Argue for that the Taylor polynomial is equal to an arbitrary polynomial whenever $n \geq k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3604949/argue-for-that-the-taylor-polynomial-is-equal-to-an-arbitrary-polynomial-wheneve) but my TA said that this was not enough.

Comment: You must first show that $T_n(x) $and $p(x) $ are equal upto order n whenever $n\ge k$. For that, show that $\lim_{x\to x_o} \frac{R_n(f)} {(x-x_o)^n} =0$, which implies $T_n(x) =p(x)$.

Comment: So I am not just able to calculate the above integral? My TA told me to specifically use a sentence in my book and the above is the only I can find which makes any sense in terms of what I want to show ..

Comment: I think he might be referring to " Taylor polynomial coefficients $a_i$'s are 0 for$ i\gt k$"

Answer (score 1):

Note that, whenever $n\ge k$, we have $\lim_{x\to x_o} \frac{R_n(f)} {(x-x_o)^n} =0 \tag{1}$ ,This is because of Taylor polynomial coefficients 
$a_i= p^{(i)} /i! =0$ for $i\gt k$. 
If $p(x) \ne T_n(x) $, let $R(x) = p(x) - T_n(x) \;\text{[note that degree of p(x) is $\le$ k and that of $T_n$ is $\le n$] } $ 
Therefore assume that, $R(x)=c_o+c_1(x-x_o) +c_2(x-x_o)^2+...+c_n(x-x_o)^n$ 
 Using (1), $c_n=... =c_2=c_1=0$.
Hence, $p(x) = T_n(x) $